# Can you set the value of a third option URL path() dictionary with a URL template tag parameter in django?

Tags: django, django-urls

I need to pass an extra param to a url, but don't want to add it to the url pattern.  Reading the django docs, I came across [this](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/http/urls/#passing-extra-options-to-view-functions), which is a bit like:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('blog/<pk>/', views.year_archive, {'foo': 'bar'}),
]
```

Sounds like what I need, but is there a way to set the value of 'bar' with a url tag, something like:

```
data-url="{% url 'name_of_view' pk=obj.id foo=obj.bar %}"  or...
data-url="{% url 'name_of_view' obj.id obj.bar %}"  or... ???
```

Also tried things like:

```
path('blog/<pk>/', views.year_archive, {'foo': <bar>}),
path('blog/<pk>/', views.year_archive, {'foo': self.bar}), #don't know why I think that would work
```

Of course none of that works.  I can pass 'obj.bar' through its own url pattern which is easy enough, but this breaks some other dependent code.  Looking for another way, and the third option url dictionary seems promising if I can get it to work but so far can't set the value from the template.

Comment: The third dictionary parameter for urls is not overridable. You could use GET parameters or you could add a second url pattern that takes the additional parameter

Comment: I was afraid of that. Seems like a pretty limited use case dictionary if you can't set it dynamically.

Comment: The intended purpose of that parameter is for overriding some generic attributes of generic views. It is fairly limited, yes

Comment: Hmm, interesting, thanks.  I really think django could use a method to piggyback some data in path() without having to pass it through the url pattern.  Maybe some day.  I had already tried a second pattern before this ask.  Solved one problem of passing the param but other views that re-use the template with the new tag get broken.  Have to figure something else out, or make this less DRY.

Comment: I think you're on to something with GET params, thanks for that tip.  Thought about using POST as well, and concatenating my strings into existing params and splitting them out on the view, but that feels very hacky.  When I get this working I'll post some code again in case it helps somebody.

Answer (score 0):

Iain Shelvington put me on the right track. To recap, I had a param I wanted to pass through the URL but adding it to the url pattern (even with a separate dedicated pattern) broke some other dependent bits in my case.

I was able to pass my parameter (obj.brand_slug) thus:

**template:**

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-outline-dark btn-block btn-sm js-ajax-selector"
            data-url="{% url 'profile_select' product.id %}?brand={{obj.brand_slug}}">
            <b>{{product.full_product_name}}</b>
        </button>
```

And pick it up in the view..

**views.py:**

```
def product_selector(request, pk):
    profile_slug = request.GET['brand']
    # logic to work with profile slug here...
```

Easy!  Thanks Iain.  Works like a charm.

Comment: By the way, if any of django core devs or fellows [#carltongibson] are reading this, how about a way to set and pass a separate dictionary in path() in Django 3.1?  That'd be amazing.  Just sayin'.